# Adding a clickable icon to jFace table column header

Tags: swt, jface

Is it possible to add an icon to a jFace table column header with a text and make the icon separately clickable (Add listeners to the icon)

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible for the standard `TableColumn`.

Comment: No. You might be able to craft you own control that sits above the table, but that is hard work. You could also look at [NatTable](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/) which might have something (I don't use it so can't say for sure).